# Show that for every positive integer n, one can find n + 1 linearly independent vectors in $F(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $\mathbf{Hint}:$ Look for polynomials

This is from Anton and Torres linear algebra book.

For the polynomials $P_n$ in $F(-\infty, \infty)$, each vector is of the form:
$p_n = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n$
This vector can be written as a linear combination of the form:
$p_n = (a_0 + 0 + 0 + \dots + 0) + \\
\quad \quad \, (0 + a_1x+0+\dots+0) + \\
\quad \quad \, (0 + 0 + a_2x^2 + \dots + 0 ) + \\
\quad \quad \,\,\, \vdots \,+\, \vdots \,+\,\,\, \vdots \quad +\, \dots + \vdots) + \\
\quad \quad \, (0 + 0 + 0 + \dots + a_nx^n )
\\
$

Which is n+1 linearly independent vectors.
Is what I did too simplistic, correct or wrong?
Also, any suggestions on what to use in mathjax for that structure I just built. I think I used some clunky language making that. I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

There is a second part to this question that says:

> use the result in part a) to prove that $F(-\infty,\infty)$ is infinite-dimensional.

I'm not really sure how to start this. I have to do some research, but some pointers here could be handy too.

Comment: Maybe for the second part, I could say that, for $F(-\infty,\infty)$ it is the entire function space up to and including $P_{\infty}$. therefore, there is not a finite set of vectors that forms a basis for this space?

Comment: Seems like they just want you to exhibit, for arbitrary $n$, a set of $n + 1$ linearly independent vectors. The vectors $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$, as you noted, satisfy these criteria.

Comment: I see. Maybe it is not as difficult as I thought it was then.